# civicrm-5.45.0-joomla install fails

Tags: joomla, installation, civicrm.settings.php

The site is currently at 5.41.1. I have tried both civicrm-5.45.0-joomla and civicrm-5.45.0-joomla-alt install packages. When I run the install multiple times, each one fails on writing a  different ZIP entry. Any ideas on what is wrong or suggestions on moving forward?  The error I get is:

> **Warning**
> JInstaller: :Install: Can't find Joomla XML setup file.
> JInstaller: :Install: Can't find XML setup file.
> Unable to write ZIP entry to file /home/customer/www/test.XXXXXXXX.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jstree/LICENSE-MIT
>
> **Error** Error installing component

From multiple install attempts: (fails on different entry):

- /home/customer/www/test.XXXXXXXX.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2_locale_tr.js
- /home/customer/www/test.XXXXXXXX.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jstree/LICENSE-MIT
- /home/customer/www/test.XXXXXXXX.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2_locale_hu.js
- /home/customer/www/test.XXXXXXXX.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/component.json

Here is the output from the Forum Post Assistant:

> > **Joomla! Instance ::** Joomla! **3.10.4**-Stable (Daraja) 11-December-2021
> > **Joomla! Platform ::**  Joomla Platform **13.1.0**-Stable (Curiosity) 24-Apr-2013
> > **Joomla! Configured ::** Yes | Writable (644) | 
> > **Configuration Options :: Offline:** false | **SEF:** true | **SEF Suffix:** true | **SEF ReWrite:** true | **.htaccess/web.config:** Yes | **GZip:** true | **Cache:** false | **CacheTime:** 15 | **CacheHandler:** file | **CachePlatformPrefix:** false | **FTP Layer:** false | **Proxy:** false | **LiveSite:**  | **Session lifetime:** 180 | **Session handler:** database | **Shared sessions:** false | **SSL:** 2 | **Error Reporting:** default | **Site Debug:** false | **Language Debug:** false | **Default Access:** 1 | **Unicode Slugs:** false | **dbConnection Type:** mysqli | **PHP Supports J! 3.10.4:** Yes | **Database Supports J! 3.10.4:** Yes | **Database Credentials Present:** Yes |
> >
> > **Host Configuration :: OS:** Linux |  **OS Version:** 3.12.18-clouder0 | **Technology:** x86_64 | **Web Server:** Apache | **Encoding:**  |  **System TMP Writable:** Yes |   **Free Disk Space :** 891.92 GiB |
> >
> > **PHP Configuration :: Version:** **7.4.27** | **PHP API:** **cgi-fcgi** | **Session Path Writable:** Yes | **Display Errors:** 0 | **Error Reporting:** 30709 | **Log Errors To:** php_errorlog | **Last Known Error:** 10th January 2022 17:06:04. | **Register Globals:**  | **Magic Quotes:**  | **Safe Mode:**  | **Allow url fopen:** 1 | **Open Base:**  | **Uploads:** 1 | **Max. Upload Size:** 256M | **Max. POST Size:** 256M | **Max. Input Time:** 120 | **Max. Execution Time:** 120 | **Memory Limit:** 768M
> >
> > **Database Configuration ::**  **Version:** **5.7.32-35-log** (Client:mysqlnd 7.4.27) | **Database Size:** 107.45 MiB | **#of Tables with config prefix:**  85 | **#of other Tables:**  165 | **User Privileges :** GRANT ALL
>
> > **PHP Extensions ::** Core (7.4.27) | date (7.4.27) | **libxml** (7.4.27) | **openssl** (7.4.27) | pcre (7.4.27) | sqlite3 (7.4.27) | **zlib** (7.4.27) | bcmath (7.4.27) | bz2 (7.4.27) | calendar (7.4.27) | ctype (7.4.27) | **curl** (7.4.27) | dba (7.4.27) | dom (20031129) | enchant (7.4.27) | hash (7.4.27) | fileinfo (7.4.27) | filter (7.4.27) | ftp (7.4.27) | gd (7.4.27) | gettext (7.4.27) | gmp (7.4.27) | SPL (7.4.27) | **iconv** (7.4.27) | session (7.4.27) | intl (7.4.27) | json (7.4.27) | **mbstring** (7.4.27) | standard (7.4.27) | mysqlnd (mysqlnd 7.4.27) | pcntl (7.4.27) | **mysqli** (7.4.27) | PDO (7.4.27) | **pdo_mysql** (7.4.27) | pdo_pgsql (7.4.27) | pdo_sqlite (7.4.27) | pgsql (7.4.27) | Phar (7.4.27) | posix (7.4.27) | pspell (7.4.27) | readline (7.4.27) | Reflection (7.4.27) | imap (7.4.27) | shmop (7.4.27) | SimpleXML (7.4.27) | soap (7.4.27) | sockets (7.4.27) | sodium (7.4.27) | exif (7.4.27) | sysvmsg (7.4.27) | sysvsem (7.4.27) | tidy (7.4.27) | tokenizer (7.4.27) | **xml** (7.4.27) | xmlreader (7.4.27) | xmlrpc (7.4.27) | xmlwriter (7.4.27) | xsl (7.4.27) | **zip** (1.15.6) | **cgi-fcgi** (7.4.27) | memcached (3.1.0-dev) | Zend OPcache (7.4.27) | Zend Engine (3.4.0) |
> > **Potential Missing Extensions ::**
> >
> > **Switch User Environment :: PHP CGI:** Yes | **Server SU:** Yes |  **PHP SU:** Yes |  **Potential Ownership Issues:** No
>
> > **Core Folders ::** images/ (755) | components/ (755) | modules/ (755) | plugins/ (755) | language/ (755) | templates/ (755) | cache/ (755) | logs/ (755) | tmp/ (755) | administrator/components/ (755) | administrator/modules/ (755) | administrator/language/ (755) | administrator/templates/ (755) | administrator/logs/ (755) |
>
> > **Components :: Site ::** 
> >  **Core ::** com_wrapper (3.0.0)  1 | com_mailto (3.0.0)  1 | 
> > **3rd Party::** WF_LINK_SEARCH_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_LINKS_JOOMLALINKS_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_AGGREGATOR_DAILYMOTION_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_AGGREGATOR_VINE_TITLE (2.6.12)  ? | WF_AGGREGATOR_YOUTUBE_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_AGGREGATOR_VIMEO_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_AGGREGATOR_VIDEO_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_AGGREGATOR_AUDIO_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_FILESYSTEM_JOOMLA_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_POPUPS_JCEMEDIABOX_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_POPUPS_WINDOW_TITLE (2.6.12)  ? | WF_LISTS_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_DIRECTIONALITY_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_LINK_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_STYLESELECT_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_REFERENCE_TITLE (2.9.11)  ? | WF_VISUALCHARS_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_FORMATSELECT_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_AUTOSAVE_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_TEXTCASE_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_CHARMAP_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_BROWSER_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_CLEANUP_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_SPELLCHECKER_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_ANCHOR_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_PRINT_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_HELP_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_SOURCE_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | JCE - Noneditable (1.0.0)  ? | WF_FONTSIZESELECT_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_FULLSCREEN_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_ARTICLE_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_EMOTIONS_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_FONTSELECT_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_PREVIEW_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_NONBREAKING_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_WORDCOUNT_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_LAYER_TITLE (2.6.12)  ? | WF_VISUALBLOCKS_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_HR_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_CONTEXTMENU_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_ATTRIBUTES_TITLE (2.9.11)  ? | WF_CLIPBOARD_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_TABLE_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_STYLE_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_IMGMANAGER_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_SEARCHREPLACE_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_FONTCOLOR_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_MEDIA_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_XHTMLXTRAS_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_KITCHENSINK_TITLE (2.9.14)  ? | WF_INLINEPOPUPS_TITLE (2.6.12)  ? |
> >
> > **Components :: Admin ::** 
> >  **Core ::** com_modules (3.0.0)  1 | com_installer (3.0.0)  1 | com_finder (3.0.0)  1 | com_checkin (3.0.0)  1 | com_admin (3.0.0)  1 | com_menus (3.0.0)  1 | com_postinstall (3.2.0)  1 | com_content (3.0.0)  1 | com_newsfeeds (3.0.0)  1 | com_login (3.0.0)  1 | com_templates (3.0.0)  1 | com_categories (3.0.0)  1 | com_cache (3.0.0)  1 | com_tags (3.1.0)  1 | com_joomlaupdate (3.10.1)  1 | com_contenthistory (3.2.0)  1 | com_cpanel (3.0.0)  1 | com_users (3.0.0)  1 | com_languages (3.0.0)  1 | com_messages (3.0.0)  1 | com_weblinks (3.9.0)  1 | com_plugins (3.0.0)  1 | com_redirect (3.0.0)  1 | com_fields (3.7.0)  1 | com_actionlogs (3.9.0)  1 | com_privacy (3.9.0)  1 | com_media (3.0.0)  1 | com_ajax (3.2.0)  1 | com_search (3.0.0)  1 | com_config (3.0.0)  1 | 
> > **3rd Party::** Akeeba (8.0.11)  1 | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/scayt.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/replace.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/pastefromword.xml)  (0.2)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/link.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/image.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/autogrow.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/pastetext.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/wysiwygarea.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/flash.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/showblocks.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/contextmenu.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/removeformat.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/undo.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/editingblock.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/templates.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/indent.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/jabout.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/filebrowser.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/smiley.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/video.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/find.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/tab.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/toolbar.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/colordialog.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/enterkey.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/dialog.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/showborders.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/audio.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/font.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/colorbutton.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/format.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/imagedragndrop.xml)  (0.1)  ? | TreeLink (1.1)  ? | Unknown (administrator/components/com_arkeditor/editor/plugins/sourcearea.xml)  (0.1)  ? | Ark Editor Statistical Module (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Cpanel Module (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Pro Module (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Update Module (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Control Panel (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Vote Module (1.0.0)  ? | com_arkeditor (2.8.5)  1 | plgCiviCRMExample (1.6.0)  ? | CiviCRM QuickIcon (2.5.0)  ? | CiviCRM System Listener (1.0)  ? | CiviCRM User Management (1.0)  ? | Search Kit (5.45.0)  ? | Contribution cancel actions (5.45.0)  ? | CKEditor4 (5.45.0)  ? | Theme: Greenwich (5.45.0)  ? | eway Single currency extension (5.45.0)  ? | Financial ACLs (5.45.0)  ? | Sequential credit notes (5.45.0)  ? | Message Administration (5.45.0)  ? | AuthX (5.45.0)  ? | OAuth Client (5.45.0)  ? | reCAPTCHA (5.45.0)  ? | FlexMailer (5.45.0)  ? | Event Cart (5.45.0)  ? | Form Core (5.45.0)  ? | Form Code Editor (5.45.0)  ? | Form Builder (5.45.0)  ? | Mock Form Collection (5.45.0)  ? | PayPal Payflow Pro Integration (5.45.0)  ? | iATS Payments (1.7.4)  ? | Custom search framework (5.45.0)  ? | CiviCRM (5.41.1)  1 | plgCiviCRMExample (1.6.0)  ? | CiviCRM QuickIcon (2.5.0)  ? | CiviCRM System Listener (1.0)  ? | CiviCRM User Management (1.0)  ? | Search Kit (5.45.0)  ? | Contribution cancel actions (5.45.0)  ? | Search Kit (1.0.beta3)  ? | CKEditor4 (5.45.0)  ? | Theme: Greenwich (5.45.0)  ? | eway Single currency extension (5.45.0)  ? | Financial ACLs (5.45.0)  ? | Sequential credit notes (5.45.0)  ? | Message Administration (5.45.0)  ? | API v4 (4.1.0)  ? | AuthX (5.45.0)  ? | OAuth Client (5.45.0)  ? | reCAPTCHA (5.45.0)  ? | FlexMailer (5.45.0)  ? | Event Cart (5.45.0)  ? | Form Core (5.45.0)  ? | Form Code Editor (5.45.0)  ? | Form Builder (5.45.0)  ? | Mock Form Collection (5.45.0)  ? | PayPal Payflow Pro Integration (5.45.0)  ? | iATS Payments (1.7.4)  ? | Custom search framework (5.45.0)  ? | COM_JCE (2.9.14)  1 | CiviCRM (5.19.1)  1 | plgCiviCRMExample (1.6.0)  ? | CiviCRM QuickIcon (2.5.0)  ? | CiviCRM System Listener (1.0)  ? | CiviCRM User Management (1.0)  ? | API v4 (4.3.0)  ? | iATS Payments (1.6.2)  ? | COM_ARKMANAGER (2.0.1)  1 |
> >
> > **Modules :: Site ::** 
> >  **Core ::** mod_syndicate (3.0.0)  1 | mod_whosonline (3.0.0)  1 | mod_articles_news (3.0.0)  1 | mod_related_items (3.0.0)  1 | mod_articles_archive (3.0.0)  1 | mod_tags_popular (3.1.0)  1 | mod_users_latest (3.0.0)  1 | mod_feed (3.0.0)  1 | mod_finder (3.0.0)  1 | mod_languages (3.5.0)  1 | mod_articles_popular (3.0.0)  1 | mod_breadcrumbs (3.0.0)  1 | mod_footer (3.0.0)  1 | mod_custom (3.0.0)  1 | mod_articles_category (3.0.0)  1 | mod_random_image (3.0.0)  1 | mod_stats (3.0.0)  1 | mod_login (3.0.0)  1 | mod_wrapper (3.0.0)  1 | mod_articles_latest (3.0.0)  1 | mod_articles_categories (3.0.0)  1 | mod_tags_similar (3.1.0)  1 | mod_menu (3.0.0)  1 | mod_weblinks (3.9.0)  1 | mod_search (3.0.0)  1 | 
> > **3rd Party::** Simple Spotlight (3.1)  1 | ARI Ext Menu (2.2.11)  1 | MOD_EASYFOLDERLISTING (2.9)  1 | Custom Inline HTML (1.0)  1 | TheGrue Menu (3.3)  1 | Simple File Upload v1.3 (for Joomla (1.3)  ? |
> >
> > **Modules :: Admin ::** 
> >  **Core ::** mod_toolbar (3.0.0)  1 | mod_version (3.0.0)  1 | mod_latest (3.0.0)  1 | mod_logged (3.0.0)  1 | mod_title (3.0.0)  1 | mod_privacy_dashboard (3.9.0)  1 | mod_popular (3.0.0)  1 | mod_feed (3.0.0)  1 | mod_quickicon (3.0.0)  1 | mod_custom (3.0.0)  1 | mod_stats_admin (3.0.0)  1 | mod_submenu (3.0.0)  1 | mod_sampledata (3.8.0)  1 | mod_login (3.0.0)  1 | mod_menu (3.0.0)  1 | mod_status (3.0.0)  1 | mod_latestactions (3.9.0)  1 | 
> > **3rd Party::** Ark Editor Statistical Module (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Cpanel Module (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Pro Module (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Update Module (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Control Panel (1.0.0)  ? | Ark Editor Vote Module (1.0.0)  ? |
> >
> > **Libraries ::** 
> >  **Core ::** 
> > **3rd Party::** file_fof40 (4.1.1)  ? | file_fof30 (3.6.2)  ? |
>
> > **Templates :: Site ::** protostar (1.0)  ? | rexford-XXXX (1.0.a)  1 | beez3 (3.1.0)  ? |
> > **Templates :: Admin ::** **isis (1.0)**  1 | hathor (3.0.0)  1 |

Comment: Is this on your own server or shared hosting?

Comment: the site is on shared hosting at siteground. max_execution_time = 120 and I can't change it on shared hosting.